# Splitting polyline with ArcGIS Pro snapping environment?

Tags: editing, snapping, arcgis-pro

I would like to take advantage of the 64-bit environment and speedier screen refreshing for **some** editing we do.

Although I personally don't find the ribbon interface very intuitive, the ArcGIS Pro editing environment seems quite nice. **Except I found a problem....**

When I set my snapping to only Intersection and Vertex I am unable to SPLIT my polylines at intersections and vertices. Instead, **in most situations, the line is split somewhere near the intersection or vertex but not exactly at intersection/vertex**.

The problem occurs when snapping options are set to either pixels or units. I tested it on 3 different machines, using different spatial references, and in both ArcGIS Pro 1.0.0 and 1.0.2.

I expect the line to be spit exactly where it snaps at vertices or intersections but I am simply not able to.

a result of line split when snapped to vertices:

[image]

a result of a line split at intersection:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This turned out to be a bug in the way the split line tool works with snapping rather than snapping itself.

This is fixed in ArcGIS Pro 1.1 Final.