# Snapping of ArcGIS Online features fails in ArcGIS pro

Tags: editing, arcgis-online, snapping, feature-service, arcgis-pro

I'd like to edit a feature-layer that is published in ArcGIS Online with ArcGIS pro. I urgently require the snapping function. However, after enabling snapping I can only snap to the feature that is edited but not to other features of the layer. Does anyone has an idea how to solve this problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had a Pro snapping related bug that rendered the software unusable for my purposes. The issue is described here: [Splitting polyline with ArcGIS Pro snapping environment?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/150302/is-there-a-problem-with-arcgis-pro-snapping-environment)

I contacted ESRI and they confirmed that there was a problem.  I was told that the issue will be adressed in a 1.1 release.  I donwloaded the 1.1 beta and it still had the issue but I was assured that the fix will be included in an official 1.1 release.

Try downloading the latest version. Hopefully this is a related issue.

EDIT:
I was curious, so I just downloaded and installed version 1.1 (which is now out of Beta and the current official release) and it seems that the editing/snapping I described in the post linked above has been fixed.

Comment: Thanks for the response, but 'unfortunately' I already have the newest version of ArcGIS pro installed and still snapping of the ArcGIS Online feature layer doesn't work. I contacted the ESRI support and hope to receive a positive reply ...

Comment: You are trying to snap to "online" feature layer?  Is it a vector layer? I doubt that works for ESRI basemap "raster" layers (topography, etc.) Go to your contents, click the "LIst by Snapping" icon, right click on the layer and set  "Make this the only snappable layer".  If the option is there and you cannot do so, I am pretty sure you cannot snap to that particular layer.

Comment: You are right! So far, I only enabled snapping in the toolbar, but one has to go in the Table of Content to toggle it there in the "List of snapping". I wasn't aware of this additional function in ArcGIS pro before. Thanks!

Comment: Year 2020, ArcGIS Pro version 2.4.2 and is still impossible to snap to any type of vector web layer or vector tiles. I have tryied everything and sadly AGPro is still not capable to do so.